# Backslash ignored while operating a command in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, backslash

I am trying to run some steps in a software by setting up commands within python as follows :

## The commands

```
cmd="ximage <<EOF\nread image.img\ndetect\\snr=3"
os.system(cmd)
```

When I execute the last command, it ignored the backslash and gives me the following error :

```
[XIMAGE> read image.img
Image size = 1000 x 1000 pixels
[XIMAGE> detect\snr=3
 invalid command name "detectsnr=3"
```

It ignores the backslash while executing the command, although it shows the backslash in the command line. Has anyone seen this issue before ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i actualy just think it wont allow backslahes and since \s is not an escape, it was just removed, well thats just my two cent

Comment: the subcommands use slashes not backslashes, so you're right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My advice: eliminate the middleman and make your code more portable by using `subprocess` & redirection of the input

Moreover, here, the real issue is that you have to use `/` not `\` for your command (reference: [ximage manual](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/xanadu/ximage/manual/node7.html#SECTION007200000000000000000)).

> ```
> detect/snr_threshold=x
> Change the signal to noise acceptance threshold from its default value of 2.
> ```

Backslashes are just eliminated from the parsing, no matter how many you're going to put there...

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["ximage"],stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
out,err = p.communicate(b"read image.img\ndetect/snr=3")
returncode = p.wait()
```

Like this you can pass the string without risking it being interpreted by the underlying shell (one of the reasons why `os.system` is deprecated) and it's portable for instance on Windows.

`subprocess.communicate` takes the input string as argument (of type `bytes` hence the `b` prefix)

Comment: you mean to enter `detect\snr=3` ?

Comment: yes, and the code seems to recognize "\", but ignores it while executing, hence the error.